# Añadir propiedad a una colección vía LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

Dispongo de dos clases:

```
 class Preguntas
    {
        public int idPregunta;
        public string Pregunta;
    }

    class PreguntasClientes
    {
        public int idCliente;
        public int idPregunta;
        public string Pregunta;
    }
```

Y dos colecciones de esas mismas clases:

```
    List<Preguntas> lstPreguntas = new List<Preguntas>();
    List<PreguntasClientes> lstPreguntasClientes = new List<PreguntasClientes>();
```

La primera colección viene rellena con los valores de una tabla maestra:

```
        lstPreguntas.Add(new Preguntas()
        {
            idPregunta = 1,
            Pregunta = "¿Su pedido llegó a tiempo?"
        });

        lstPreguntas.Add(new Preguntas()
        {
            idPregunta = 2,
            Pregunta = "¿La atención fue correcta?"
        });
```

Y lo que quiero hacer es rellenar la segunda, con los valores de la primera, más un valor añadido que siempre será el mismo.

Obviamente esto puedo hacerlo de esta manera:

```
        //Sustituir por one-line linq
        foreach (Preguntas p in lstPreguntas)
        {
            lstPreguntasClientes.Add(new PreguntasClientes()
            {
                idPregunta = p.idPregunta,
                Pregunta = p.Pregunta,
                idCliente = 1
            });
        }
```

..pero deseo encontrar la más elegante de las soluciones a este problema, a ser posible en una sola línea.

Muchas gracias

Comment: no le veo el problema a ocupar lineas de codigo para que sea de facil lectura y a su vez sera de facil mantenimiento cuando debas leerlo.

Comment: Me alegra saberlo @RamiroBarone , pero la pregunta no es si te parece bien o no

Comment: claro, lo mio no es una respuesta, es un comentario. Y Linq es un lenguaje de consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podria ser utilizando el metodo `.ForEach` de la clase `List<T>`

```
    lstPreguntas.ForEach(
        action: (p) => {
            lstPreguntasClientes.Add(
                new PreguntasClientes() {
                   idPregunta = p.idPregunta,
                   Pregunta = p.Pregunta,
                   idCliente = 1
                }
            );
        }
    );
```

Ahora , si realmente desea una sola línea puede crear un metodo que con base en una instancia de `Preguntas` construya una instancia de `PreguntasClientes` y sustituir ese metodo por la lambda, o sobrecargar en la clase `Preguntas` un operador de conversion a la clase `PreguntasClientes`, pero si el valor de `idCliente` es 1 siempre que desee la conversion